# How to determine if one list contains another?

Tags: python, list

Is there a built-in Pythonic way to determine if one list completely contains the contents of another, including duplicated entries but disregarding the order of items?

```
>>> l1 = [2, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = [2, 2]
>>> l3 = [3, 2]
>>> l4 = [2, 2, 2]
>>> l5 = [2, 5, 2]

>>> is_superset(l1, l2)
True
>>> is_superset(l1, l3)
True
>>> is_superset(l1, l4)
False
>>> is_superset(l1, l5)
False
```

Comment: @Patrick: That question is about a subsequence test; this question is looking for a sub-multiset test.

Comment: @user2357112 if a set A is a subset of a set B, B is a superset of A

Comment: `all([l1.count(item) >= l2.count(item) for item in l2])`? Very inefficient though.

Comment: I'm not sure about your indented "including duplicated entries". Do you mean that l1 is a superset of l3, but l3 is not a superset of l1?

Comment: @abarnert Precisely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there were no duplicates, or duplicates didn't matter (that is, if your `l1` and `l3` were both supersets of each other), you'd just use sets. But since if you want `l1` to be a proper superset of `l3`, you're talking about multisets. Fortunately, [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) already implements multisets for you:

```
from collections import Counter
def is_superset(a, b):
    return not Counter(b) - Counter(a)
```

Notice that this `-` is proper multiset difference between multisets (just as `-` is proper set difference between `set`s), not an elementwise subtraction across dicts. So if you subtract a super(multi)set, you get an empty multiset (that is, `Counter()`—which is, like all empty collections in Python, falsey).

So now:

```
>>> is_superset(l1, l2)
True
>>> is_superset(l1, l3)
True
>>> is_superset(l1, l4)
False
>>> is_superset(l1, l5)
False
```

Plus:

```
>>> is_superset(l3, l1)
False
```

Comment: Never heard of it, what is the semantics of `bool(Counter(..))`? Is there a documentation page on it?

Comment: @BenUsman It's the same as _every_ collection in Python: empty collections are falsey, non-empty ones are true. (There are a few quasi-collections in third-party code, most famously numpy arrays, where that isn't true, but `Counter` isn't one of them.)

Comment: @BenUsman See [Boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) on the builtins, [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) on falling back to `__len__`. Beyond that, I guess it's not explicitly defined, but the fact that a `Counter` is defined as "a dict subclass" _implies_ that it should follow the same rules as dict, in the same way that it implies that `len` works. If you don't trust that, there's [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L451)

Comment: thanks! The falseness of empty collections is indeed intuitive. I did not know that `Counter` supports all these algebraic operations similarly to `set`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

def is_superset(l1, l2):
    c1, c2 = Counter(l1), Counter(l2)
    return all(c1[k] >= c2[k] for k in c2)
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `k in c1` check.

Comment: Right, forgot Counters give 0 for non existent keys. Thanks

Comment: Just subtract the counters. It's not elementwise subtraction, it's multiset subtraction, so you will get back an empty multiset if you subtract a super(multi)set. Or intersect them, as in [fferri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50180446/908494). Either way, if you're going to use a Counter as a multiset, take advantage of it being a multiset to write the intuitive multiset operation.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and the builtin intersection method:

```
from collections import Counter

def is_superset(l1, l2):
    c1, c2 = Counter(l1), Counter(l2)
    return c1 & c2 == c2
```

Test:

```
>>> l1 = [2, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = [2, 2]
>>> l3 = [3, 2]
>>> l4 = [2, 2, 2]
>>> l5 = [2, 5, 2]
>>> is_superset(l1, l2)
True
>>> is_superset(l1, l3)
True
>>> is_superset(l1, l4)
False
>>> is_superset(l1, l5)
False
>>>
```

Comment: Somebody downvotes this question as soon as @fferri post question. Why ?

Comment: It may be worth parenthesizing `c1 & c2` for clarity; while Python's precedence puts `&` at higher precedence than `==`, many other languages have it the other way.

Comment: The other way would read `return c1 & True` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think intersection may actually be clearer than set difference here, so I have no idea why someone downvoted your answer but not mine. Maybe just because they're a C user and were confused by the point that @user2357112 suggested clarifying?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an inefficient solution that verifies that for each element in the sublist, its occurrence number in the sublist must be lower or equal than its occurrence number in the superlist:

```
def is_superset(l1, l2):
    return all([l1.count(item) >= l2.count(item) for item in l2])
```